# Xcode 7.3, Swift 2.2 Storyboards Extremely Slow

Tags: xcode, performance, storyboard, xcode7.3, swift2

I have a huge app in process, and since updating to Xcode 7.3, doing anything in storyboard is like molasses!!

About a month ago, I had about the same speed using one HUGE storyboard, so I split the project up into 5 separate storyboards, and Hallelujah, a hundred times faster!
But now, after updating, even dividing to 7; slow as can be!
I'm about to back up, then try and recreate one big one, then back up again, then divide again - to see if that does anything; but I am doubtful.

Anyone know how to fix this, or what is wrong with the latest update?

Comment: Everything is fine for me. My mac opens the storyboards quickly. Although if the storyboard has IBDesignable Classes used, it takes 1 - 2 sec. to load but in rest of the cases it is quick.  I believe your MAC would be out dated.

Comment: 2015 MacBook Pro
2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Using
El Capitan
…Probably not

Comment: LOL, your configuration seems latest one, yet you are facing issues, and mine is older than yours but runs faster with huge storyboards. :D :D

Comment: Are you using IBDesignable libraries in your project ?

Comment: Probably not (since I don't know what IBDesignable libraries are - haha). I have about 150 classes of which about 35 are View Controllers. I try and put as much as I can in code rather than in storyboard, but I know I have a couple VCs that need serious revamping to reduce needless views (e.g.: use programmatic collection views instead). Its got to be something stupid and obscure that is causing the problem

Comment: Update: so far, I have put all of the storyboards together and funny, working in the storyboard is no longer slow, HOWEVER, its so big that it takes 3 minutes to enter or exit the storyboard. And, of course, at least 3 minutes to compile the stink'n thing. So, a trade off so far. Now comes part 2: disassemble into multiple storyboards again..., see if that works. Get back to you (...anyone interested or with the same issue that is)

Comment: In Xcode 7.3, I am still facing the issues. I have 45 `UIViewController` in `Main.StoryBoard` and putting a `UILabel` in any of the `UIStoryBoard` takes 1 - 2 hours. So, it's extremely extremely slow :(

Comment: I split into 8 storyboards, and most are now manageable but still nowhere near as quick as before 7.3
And at least one storyboard (one with an MKMap) is EXCRUCIATINGLY slow.
...it's the weekend right now and so I have family responsibilities, but Monday I plan on taking that view apart and seeing if I can find a culprit

Answer (score 1):

Well, not a great solution but, all I can determine is that; if the number of items and constraints in the view gets over a certain amount (using Xcode 7.3), the speed suddenly drops horribly.
So what I ended up having to do with this last storyboard (8 of 8) is to take a slide out side pane full of buttons and subviews, and place it in a container view - so that I could give it its own VC and thereby make it a stand alone 9th storyboard.

Not a great solution that's for sure, especially since I had to tie all of the buttons and methods to the parent view controller. I was lucky in this event in that the parent view (my main app map) is a single instance occurrence so I was able to reference it at launch, and merely prefix my former methods with the reference. If this was not so, I guess I would have to have done some serious protocol / delegation.

So, a proper solution (or 'fix' if it is Xcode's doing) is still wanting :)